# Loading content from a div from another website into an iframe on current page

Tags: javascript

I was able to get a full page loaded into an iframe but I want a certain part of the page.  I know the div id of what I need. This is my current code

```
onload=function(){
       var el=document.getElementById("frameContainer")
       el.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"url\"></iframe>"
}
```

I was thinking of getting the full page and then grabbing the div from there and displaying it but I couldn't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

cross-domain issues are likely to foil you. consider some sort of server-side/curl-ish solution instead?

Comment: I am not able to touch anything on the server or download anything for this. Basically I can work directly with javascript, css, and js of the webpage i am currently working on.